# Store values in separate, C# type-specific columns or all in one column?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building a C# project configuration system that will store configuration values in a SQL Server db.

I was originally going to set the table up as such:

```
KeyId        int
FieldName    varchar
DataType     varchar
StringValue  varchar
IntValue     int
DecimalValue decimal
...
```

Values would be stored and retrieved with the value in the DataType column determining which Value column to use, but I really don't like that design. So I thought I'd go this route:

```
KeyId        int
FieldName    varchar
DataType     varchar
Value        varbinary
```

Here the value in DataType would still determine the type of Value brought back, but it would all be in one column and I wouldn't have to write a ton of overloads to accommodate the different types like I would have with the previous solution. I would just pull the Value in as a byte array and use DataType to perform whatever conversion(s) necessary to get my Value.

Is the varbinary approach going to cause any performance issues or is it just bad practice to drop all these different types of data into a varbinary? I've been searching around for about an hour and I can't get to a definitive answer.

Also, if there is a more preferred method anyone can think of to reach the same conclusion, I'm all ears (or eyes).

Comment: There's not a definitive answer. There are pros and cons both ways.

Comment: This smells of "inner platform effect" (using a database table to construct a logical database table). If this is *just* configuration name/value pairs, I'd probably just use strings throughout (perhaps base-64 or hex for any true binary data you need to store). But if this is your actual data: avoid this (anti-)pattern - for actual data you should have a well-named/typed regular column per value

Comment: @MarcGravell You make a good point. This is just a key/value pair situation where something like a Web.config file can be constructed so if, for instance, one of our database server names change, we can just edit the configuration value for the projects that use that database.

So in your opinion, is the better solution to store everything as a JSON string as ManOVision noted below?

Comment: @Tim for that scenario I just use a table with nvarchar columns name and value (row per name/value pair) - easier if you need to script changes in SQL (fun fact: that is how the configuration system for stackoverflow.com works, plus a few nullables columns for "site", "data-center", etc - for per-site config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the second solution and it works well. Remember, that the disk access is in orders of magnitude greater, than the ex. casting operation (it's milliseconds vs. nanoseconds, see [ref](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)), so do not look for bottleneck here.
The solution can be to implement polymorphic association ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449031/3922292), [2](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sql-antipatterns/9781680500073/f_0043.html)). But I dont think there is a need for that, or that you should do this. The second solution is close to non-Sql db - you can dump as a value anything, might be as well entire html markup for a page. It should be the caller responsability to know what to do wit the data.

Also, see threads on how to store settings in DB: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6893803/3922292), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204902/database-design-for-user-settings) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514603/key-value-pairs-in-a-database-table) for critique.

Answer (score 2):

You could serialize your settings as JSON and just store that as a string. Then you have all the settings within one row and your clients can deserialize as needed. This is also a safe way to add additional settings at any time without any modifications to your database.

Comment: I'm accepting Piotr Falkowski's answer only because it's the one I'm going to use. As much as I wanted to use this answer, I couldn't 100% fit it into some of the outlying requirements. Thank you for this, though! It's definitely something I will keep in mind in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good luck with your implementation.